# Процессор всё время перезагружается

Tags: железо

У меня проблема: когда нажимаешь на кнопку Power процессора, то он начинает всё время перезагружаться, да так быстро, что даже на мониторе ничего не успевает отобразиться и лампочка загореться и куллеры запуститься! Когда три раза перегрузится, притормаживает, включает лампочку power, включает куллеры, а потом опять всё сначала... Думал, может электричества не хватает, включил в другую розетку отдельно от монитора и т.п., но всё равно так!

Вопрос: почему так!? Что делать?! Может ли вирус так!? (Думаю, что вряд ли, а что это тогда?)

P.S. Мне запчасти не меняли, с теми же, что сейчас, недавно процессор прекрасно работал. Думал, что кнопку перезагрузки заело... проверил... вроде нет! Может блок питания сгорел? Как это проверить? Вроде горелым не воняет...

Comment: Для начала, переформулируйте вопрос в соответствии с терминологией (ибо [процессор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Процессор), [электричество](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Электричество)). Кроме того постарайтесь более ясно сформулировать, что происходит, что вы подразумеваете под "три раза перезагрузится"? Как определяете, что он именно "перезагружается"?Что было до того как это начало происходить? Что делали? Как проверяли?

Comment: Лампочка питания первые 3 перезагрузки не горит а винчетерная корит потом горят обе 1 раз а потом опятьПод перезагрузкой я подразумеваю то что начинают крутится вентиляторы монитор на 1 сек показывает чёный экран потом опять выключается и опять так

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На материнской плата отбросить проводок идущий к кнопке reset, включить компьютер, если не помогло, идем дальше и снимаем проводок кнопки power. Освободившиеся контакты кратковременно замыкаем отверткой, компьютер должен включиться. Если и это не помогло ищем другой блок питания. Но перед тем как все это проделать надо внимательно изучить "материнку" на предмет вздувшихся емкостей. Если онные обнаружены, то это прямой путь в магазин радиотоваров и последущая замена конденсаторов прямыми руками и импульсным паяльником.

Answer (score 0):

"Залипает" кнопка Power. Попробуйте перегрузить из консоли командой shutdown.

```
$sudo shutdown -r now
```

либо

```
$sudo reboot
```

либо

```
$init 6
```

Для Windows, думаю,

```
shutdown -r
```

Comment: Поподробней можно? как?

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: Так я немогу даже на мониторе картинку увидеть даже куллеры не врубаются....

Answer (score 0):

"Для Windows, думаю,

shutdown -r"Для Windows нужно ещё время указать ключом "-t".